# Now save() return false in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

About one change of Laravel 5.3,

Now, I have a model I want to save.

Before, I was doing :

```
$result = $model->save();
```

And I could know if operation is successful.

Now, with the new:

> The Eloquent save method now returns false if the model has not been changed since the last time it was retrieved or saved.

mentioned in the [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0)

If the model has not changed, it return false.

Now my code tell me there were an error, because I trust true or false to be the result of good or bad operation.

So now, How can I check that save() was successful, even if it didn't change data???

Comment: where does it say it returns false in 5.3?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0

Comment: Full quotation makes more sense than the without context quote above `The Eloquent save method now returns false if the model has not been changed since the last time it was retrieved or saved.` Seems to imply that if you loaded a model and immediately used `save()` it would return false instead of true previously.

Comment: have you tried `update()` instead?

Comment: @Blake is right i think... you would have to save immediately for it to return false

Comment: I would assume, that an exception would be thrown if something went wrong.

Comment: I guess update will do the trick. Tx

Comment: This `save()` behavior is no longer current in version 5.3 as it got removed from the upgrade guide doc in this [commit](https://github.com/laravel/docs/commit/433259209c0f27c51baf90df5610b0ca7dea29d6). This change was also discussed in this [PR](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/15236) and later merged into the Laravel's 5.3 source. Laravel's project creator also recommends to ignore the `save()` method return entirely: `There is never a good reason to do so`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if your model is Dirty.

```
//               A                    B
$result = !$model->isDirty() || $model->save()
```

- If your model was modified, `A` will be `false`, but `B` should be `true`. So `$result` will be `true`
- If your model was not modified, `A` will be `true`, so `$result` will be true.
- If your model was modified and didn't saved sucessfull, you will get `false` both in `A` and `B`, so `$result` will be false.

---

**I explain:** This happens because Eloquent just do an DB query **IF** something changed. Laravel developers decided to change the `save()` response, so now you can know if a query was made, or if anything changed.

---

According to @patricus comment, the first solution will not trigger the `saving()` and `updating` events, for a obvious reason: **PHP as many languages will stop evaluating an OR expression when a `true` is found.**

So if you need this events being triggered, you should do this:

```
$wasClean = $model->isClean(); // The oposite of 'isDirty()'
$result = $model->save() || $wasClean;
```

Comment: There are two caveats to this method. First, if there is a `saving()` event on the model, this method will prevent that from being called when the model is not dirty. Second, if attempting to insert a new, empty record into the database, this method will prevent that.

Comment: Also, the model has an `isClean()` method, if you'd prefer to use that over `! isDirty()`.

Comment: @patricus Added a new answer

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro There is an update to the answer, in case it is relevant to your situation.